# Which plugin is required to have docker.build work in Jenkins?

Tags: linux, macos, docker, jenkins

I am using docker on Mac and have Jenkins running in docker container.

Client is interacting with docker daemon on host machine.

I have following plugins installed:

- docker-plugin
- workflow-aggregator

I do have `docker` client / command working in container. I have also checked it using `sh` and even docker cloud can spin up agents.

But below Jenkinsfile is contantly throwing error.

```
def image

pipeline {
    agent {
        label "container"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    image = docker.build("username/image:$BUILD")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am constantly facing below error message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: docker for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error: `No such property: docker for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

No such **Docker** property indicates that [Docker Pipeline plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/) is not installed.

It's little confusing because name of these three plugins are very much similar to each other's id:

- [Docker](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/) have id `docker-plugin`
- [Pipeline plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator/) have id `workflow-aggregator`
- [Docker Pipeline plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/) have id `docker-workflow`

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: docker for class: groovy.lang.Binding.

We most likely encountered the same issue, in order to fix it I only had to install the **Docker Pipeline plugin** in Jenkins, so all you have to do is go to:

**Jenkins Homepage > Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Available**

Search for **Docker Pipeline** install it restart jenkins and you are ready to go.

For more info about **Docker Pipeline Plugin Scripts** click [here](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/plugins/docker-workflow).